# Virtualbox display issue

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I installed Virtualbox on Mac and then installed Ubuntu on Virtualbox as a virtual machine. My Ubuntu display comes as 640 X 480 (4:3) resolution and cannot be changed. My actual screen resolution is 1360 X 768. I set the correct screen size in Virtualbox > preference > display. Still no success. What can I do?

(I use OS X Mavericks, Virtualbox 4.3.12, Ubuntu 14.04)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [VBoxGuestAdditions_4.3.12.iso](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/) in Ubuntu virtual machine.
 Or If you have already downloaded and mounted Virtualbox Guest additions then, Choose `Devices->Install Guest Additions..`

1.Download the above mentioned ISO.
2.Mount the ISO in Storage section in virtualbox settings as a Virtual CD. or after starting the Guest OS Ubuntu, Click `Devices->CD/DVD Devices-> Choose Virtual CD...`
3.Start up the Guest OS Ubuntu, and Open up CD image and run it. It'll take some time.
4.Power Off the virtual machine and restart and you can set it to full resolution, or choose `view-> Full screen mode`

Comment: Works fine! thank you very much. I will award my bounty to you as soon as I can:-). Thanks again.